# I did not include the word 'origin' when pushing to github

Tags: git, terminal, head

Please refer to the `git log` I have attached at the bottom

I was working on the '`listing-filters`' branch and successfully made commits up to
'`Minor css edits`' commit.

However, I accidentally missed the word `origin` and typed
'`git push listing-filters`' and it seems like these commits are pushed to `HEAD -> listing-filters`
rather than `origin/listing-filters`

The 'Design Edits on SubFilter Component' has to be pushed to origin/listing-filters branch but on my local machine everything has been applied but these commits are not pushed anywhere in the origin/listing-filters branch (even from GUI of Github).

It says '`nothing to commit`' on my screen.

Could anyone give me some tips on how to merge HEAD branch to the origin branch?

---

```sh
commit 83aef6716d8a2be6fa5195dd32cea9b4b5ebd1ad (HEAD -> listing-filters)
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 03:23:36 2020 -0700

    Testing

commit d663f88868047423404a9578d271711ef90bd459
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 03:12:13 2020 -0700

    Testing

commit 9cc3fe28dec09af1765d6df2c79634f4b1346051
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 03:11:55 2020 -0700

    Something went wrong? Commit dissappeared

commit 19dba0e67aef7d2e7abf4b3d34fce952cab29fc6
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 03:09:50 2020 -0700

    Design Edits on SubFilter Component

commit b13e6be2ddeb3c3fefa3de81effc318dd02ecd48 (origin/listing-filters, origin/d663f88)
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 01:23:51 2020 -0700

    Minor css edits

commit 5c72bd01d145b6a2baf6d82dca324aaa80f30c75
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 01:00:42 2020 -0700

    Bit of refactoring: SubFilter component can be refactored more

commit 5503ef4b59a15ffdb2c3647e4736231f60892fd4
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 00:38:23 2020 -0700

    Reseting button working fine

commit 32d77b249fa6bce6a156edcdfb28d7efbf360eb4
Author: Danny Rhee <dongyunrhee@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 22 00:30:59 2020 -0700

    Chaning the property type being properly updated/rendered
```

Comment: Just say `git push origin listing-filters` now.

Comment: The `(HEAD -> listing-filters)` annotation added to commit `83aef6716d8a2be6fa5195dd32cea9b4b5ebd1ad` is from `git log`'s `--decorate` option. It means that commit `83aef6716d8a2be6fa5195dd32cea9b4b5ebd1ad` is the current commit, and branch name `listing-filters` is the current branch. It has nothing to do with any earlier `git push` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try again, making sure you associate your local branch to the remote branch:

```
git push -u origin listing-filters
```

Check the branch is correctly associated to its upstream branch with

```
git branch -avv
```

If so, next time, a simple `git push` (no additional arguments needed) will be enough.